# How do I create a query which finds results between now and a month ago

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have database with the field name `brand_name` and `brand_opendate` (the date of opening of the brand). I want to make query that will display the `brand_name` which is having brand open date between the today's date and before the one month. What I am trying to say is that suppose today's date is `2014/02/13` then it will display the `brand_name` between `2014/01/13 and 2014/02/13`.  I need to find the current date to do this.

Comment: Have you tried writing such a query?

Comment: Which date is a month ago from 2014-03-31?  What about 2012-03-31?  Come to that, what about a month ago from 2014-05-31 (it doesn't have to be February that causes the trouble)?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `DATE_SUB()` and `NOW()`

`DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` subtracts 1 month from now, you are now looking for products which have a `brand_opendata` between last month and now.

**Example:**

```
SELECT 
    brand_name 
FROM 
    product
WHERE 
    brand_opendata BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW()
```

**REMEMBER brand_opendata must be a `DATE` column NOT a `varchar` or something.**

Next time make sure you make sure you read the [proper documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) before you start giving up.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I did not exactly find as I want that is why I have posted.

Comment: Its work perfectly. Thnaks